# Elasticsearch River Web Intergration

Tags: elasticsearch

i am trying to use elasticsearch crawler 
https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-river-web

i did all mentioned steps correctly but i dont know how to start the crawler

## like below

Start Crawler

./bin/riverweb --config-id [config doc id] --cluster-name [Elasticsearch Cluster Name] --cleanup
For example,

## ./bin/riverweb --config-id my_web --cluster-name elasticsearch --cleanup

how to do this step ???
i dont know what dose he mean or which tool to use !!

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the command within directory.`(./bin/riverweb --config-id my_web --cluster-name elasticsearch --cleanup)`.

For example, I have downloaded **elasticsearch-river-web-1.5.1.tar.gz**,so I decompress this tar,and then I enter within directory (**elasticsearch-river-web-1.5.1**) and I execute the command.

Moreover,there is a folder within directory where you can check log,file's name is **riverweb.log**.

Cheers